# Okular pdf closes the previous window when clicking on hyperlink

Tags: pdf, latex, okular

Im using Okular 23.04.0 with Kubuntu. I create pdf documents with Kile-latex. I have hyperlinks to other pdfs created and always when I click on the hyperlink it opens a new pdf and closes an old one. I want to open it in a new tab or in a new window. It doesn't work with hyperlinks only- otherwise, it works. Please help me.